# can't start tomcat via netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

Netbeans 7.2, tomcat 7.0.27

Standard route - installed netbeans with embedded tomcat. Created a simple Java web application template and tried to run it.

Tomcat logs:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "D:\Documents and Settings\lkoniecz\Application Data\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.27.0_base"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.27"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\Documents and Settings\lkoniecz\Application Data\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.27.0_base\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.27\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.27\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Nov 25, 2013 11:16:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;C:\WINNT\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINNT\system32;C:\WINNT;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Utilities;C:\WINNT\system32;C:\WINNT;C:\WINNT\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\ConnectUtilities;C:\Program Files\IPSec Client;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program Files\Net-SNMP\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational AppScan\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\Code Collaborator Client;.
Nov 25, 2013 11:16:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
Nov 25, 2013 11:16:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 25, 2013 11:16:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 808 ms
Nov 25, 2013 11:16:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 25, 2013 11:16:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
Nov 25, 2013 11:16:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor D:\Documents and Settings\lkoniecz\Application Data\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml
Nov 25, 2013 11:16:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor D:\Documents and Settings\lkoniecz\Application Data\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
Nov 25, 2013 11:16:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
Nov 25, 2013 11:16:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 25, 2013 11:16:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 663 ms
```

Deployment progress bar is still moving with 'waiting for tomcat'. Surprisingly tomcat works, I can access the GUI on localhost:8084. Start/stop commands are grayed out on the services tab for apache tomcat server. My app is not deployed - cant see it under tomcat webapp folder.

any help appreciated,
regards

Comment: Consider updating Netbeans to the latest release, just to rule out a bug that was already fixed.

Comment: I tried it before, but all attempts to install Netbeans 7.3 or higher resulted in error that the installation fire is not a valid win32 executable. I am using Windows XP.

Comment: Note that I have discovered a similar issue on NetBeans 8.1, starting from Tomcat 8.5.3 (prior releases did not have an issue). See  the [answer I have composed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38277506/744133) . I suspect the issue will be similar, maybe where you have changed the "server" attribute to be different from the default that NetBeans expects.