# cannot run tomcat 7 from netbeans

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, netbeans

```
path - C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin
catalina_home - C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\
```

server setting in netbeans https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mFDn.png

(the system wont let me post images)

when i hit run button tomcat throws an error:     127.0.0.1 command is not recognized as an internal or external operable program or batch file.

(using windows 7 64bit)

Comment: Tomcat doesn't throw that error, that's a standard Windows command prompt error when you invoke a command that is not recognized. Tomcat cannot even be started, so something might be very wrong with it. Can you successfully start the server on the command prompt by running the startup.bat script in the bin directory?

Comment: yes, i can start it with the startup.bat file. tomcat works fine i just cant start it from netbeans

also i did not use tomcat installer, but zip file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recent bug in Tomcat 7.0.56.

See my answer on the exact same question 8 hours ago :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26487192/1935128

Assuming you are on windows (this bug is caused by the crappy bat files escaping), It is a bug introduced in the latest versions (7.0.56 and 8.0.14) to workaround another bug. Try to remove the `"` around the JAVA_OPTS declaration in catalina.bat . It fixed it for me with tomcat 7.0.56 yesterday.

For your asterisk, it might only be a configuration of yours somewhere that appends it to the host declaration.

I saw this on Tomcat's bugtracker yesterday but I can't find the link again.
*Edit* Found it! https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56895

I hope it fixes your problem.