# Netbeans 8 Tomcat 8 start error

Tags: startup, netbeans-8, tomcat8

I'm beginner with Java EE. I try to start my Tomcat server. I use this [link](http://technology.amis.nl/2012/01/02/installing-tomcat-7-and-configuring-as-server-in-netbeans/) to configuration.

At end if i start server i have an error message :

> 127.0.0.1 n'est pas une commande interne ou externe, un programme executable ou un fichier de commandes.

Anybody can help me. Please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error starting Tomcat from NetBeans - '127.0.0.1\*' is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485487/error-starting-tomcat-from-netbeans-127-0-0-1-is-not-recognized-as-an-inter)

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look of this post, [Error starting Tomcat from NetBeans - '127.0.0.1*' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485487/error-starting-tomcat-from-netbeans-127-0-0-1-is-not-recognized-as-an-inter) ?

Quote from the post:

change

```
:noJuliConfig
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%"

..

:noJuliManager
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%"
```

to

```
:noJuliConfig
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%

.. 

:noJuliManager
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%
```

I did what suggested in the post and it solved my problem.

Comment: Rather than restating an original SO answer as a new answer, the original question needs to be marked as a duplicate of the question that was properly answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mac OS platform (could be valid for Linux environments as well, i did not try), another error appears in catalina.sh if IDE proxy is enabled. Debugging shows that below line gives an error.

Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|salvamea.local

To solve the error go to Server configuration "Platform" tab, and un-click "Use IDE proxy settings". For some reason if you need the proxy, then catalina.sh should be fixed so that the value is in double quotes.