# Error starting Tomcat from NetBeans: '127.0.0.1*' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, startup, tomcat8

I know this is duplicate of [Error starting Tomcat from NetBeans - '127.0.0.1*' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485487/error-starting-tomcat-from-netbeans-127-0-0-1-is-not-recognized-as-an-inter)

But that solution is not working for me. My catalina.bat already had those "" removed from java_opts.

I have netbeans 8.01 and Tomcat 8.

From eclipse and command prompt it is starting properly.

I don't have enough reputation to comment and ask on the same thread so I have to open a new thread.

Help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just FYI, but the linked answer you provided should be the correct solution. I suspect that you have more than one tomcat installation, a `CATALINA_HOME` that is separate from your `CATALINA_BASE`, or multiple `CATALINA_BASE`. Basically, you made the corrections in the wrong copy of the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error starting Tomcat from NetBeans - '127.0.0.1\*' is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485487/error-starting-tomcat-from-netbeans-127-0-0-1-is-not-recognized-as-an-inter)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  After making the standard "remove quotes" fix and restarting Netbeans, I was still getting the same error.  I ran the set commands from the Windows command line as administrator to ensure that the opts would get set properly without the quotes and then followed the definition of crazy and stopped and restarted Netbeans again, after which it started working.  I am not sure if running the set commands from the command line as administrator or restarting Netbeans the second time did it, but Tomcat did start successfully after this.

Answer (score -1):

Edit a file(Apache tomcat):bin/catalina.bat 
Edit 2 row:

```
:noJuliConfig
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%"

..

:noJuliManager
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%"
```

to

```
:noJuliConfig
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%

.. 

:noJuliManager
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%
```

Comment: Rather than restating an original SO answer as a new answer, the original question needs to be marked as a duplicate of the question that was properly answered. Besides, the original poster already acknowledged this solution and noted that it did not work.