# Java Debug won't unfold the WAR file On windows with netbeans

Tags: java, file, netbeans, war, tomcat8

I have a little complicated problem to explain;

I have a project that I write on Netbeans that will be used as intranet application. It was a dynamic web application. And it has some File.IO operations in it . My aim is create some files on the directory where index.html in. So I try to make the program find the directory by the code below :

```
     Session.getServletContext().getRealPath("Index.jsp");
```

But because of java version it didn't work so I used:

```
     Session.getServletContext().getContextPath();
```

Now it shows the right path on debug but not fullpath. After debug I can find my files under c:/ not under the directory where index.html in nor even nearby my projectfolder :)

So I looked at Apache folder under Programfiles under webapps and I saw that  my applications folder is not there. It didn't unfold the war file actually it seems to virtualy opens it and creates a some numbered html file under temp folder . How can I make my Tomcat work like a Tomcat on a linux system and unfold the war file and find the right folder (the main web folder) and read write files, folders etc.

Additionally I want to add the server.xml unpack config below:

```
          <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

Even if you can give me a clue I would be pleased.
Thanks,
Kaan

Comment: @Everv0id - you might want to clarify that statement a bit. Most web applications need at least some IO operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem . But there is a bunch of work to do . So I write down here one by one ;

1. **Session.getServletContext().getRealPath("Index.jsp");**  is not true . But not the main problem . in the brackets we must write a folder not a file to find the parent folder. After correct this, it will return null again . because Java EE 7 does not support getRealPath() method. but at the end this will be already solved by changing the version.
2. On Netbeans IDE , at toolbar , tools >> Servers  , I removed the
   tomcat server. and also uninstall the Apache Tomcat8 that comes with
   Netbeans8 because there may be a version problem as I read from the
   forums.
3. And I download Apache Tomcat7 from the official site of apache and
   installed service.
4. I configured tomcat-users.xml config file for admin priviledges.
5. And I add the Tomcat7 server at netbeans from the same toolbar
   (tools >> Servers)
6. What I saw was in the project the server was not there. I went inside
   project properties , from the menu > Run , and Server combo-box was
   empty. Because I was using Java EE7 and Tomcat7 needs at least Java
   EE6. So I needed to change the java ee version.

**What to do :**
Click the files tab near projects tab. Under nbproject folder , select j2ee.platform , for Tomcat7 change the platform to 1.6 (Tomcat6 > Jave EE 1.5). than make a "clean and build" on the project .
Now the server will come at Project > properties > Run > Servers

7. After that I came across with another problem : (And also you may :) ) 
   Tomcat logs from NetBeans says :

-**" '127.0.0.1*' is not recognized as an internal or external command "**

**to correct that :**   [Error starting Tomcat from NetBeans - '127.0.0.1*' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485487/error-starting-tomcat-from-netbeans-127-0-0-1-is-not-recognized-as-an-inter)