# Starting of tomcat failed.Why?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Starting of Tomcat failed.Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed.
See the server log for details.

In Apache tomcat EE this is the error:

> '127.0.0.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

And I don't have a `cataina.bat` file in my bin folder of tomcat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error starting Tomcat from NetBeans - '127.0.0.1\*' is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485487/error-starting-tomcat-from-netbeans-127-0-0-1-is-not-recognized-as-an-inter)

Comment: I dont have a catalina.bat file in my bin folder.

Comment: what is your tomcat version?!

Comment: you must have catalina.bat OR catalina.sh in your bin folder