# Getting error in running apache tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

When I try to run a servlet program in NetBeans, I get the following error in `build-impl.xml` at line 1045, which is not allowing Tomcat server to start.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And, apache server log is giving message as IP is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

I do not know where I did it wrong, or where I configured the environment variables, provided in servlet mapping.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485487/error-starting-tomcat-from-netbeans-127-0-0-1-is-not-recognized-as-an-inter

Comment: @DarshanPatel still not working... as per link provided by you..in that i am not able to edit catlina.bat...on saving the edited part it is giving error as this file is for read only.

Comment: Search notepad in start -> right click -> run as administrative -> Go to desired path and open file -> then edit your changes and save it.

Comment: @DarshanPatel thanks editing works.....this way.

Comment: @DarshanPatel but i am getting error at build-impl.xml line no:1045--- Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is some issue in tomcat which comes with netbeans or permission issue in Windows.

Follow below steps to resolve :

1) Remove your current tomcat. (Tools --> servers --> select tomcat --> remove)

2) Download latest tomcat from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi)

3) Extract it (Not in system drive)

4) Go to Tools --> servers --> click on add server

5) From Server list choose Apache Tomcat or TomEE element.

[image]

6) Choose server location by clicking the Browse button.

[image]

7) Click on Finish.

8) Start tomcat.

Hope this will resolve your issue.