# How to shutdown a Tomcat's instance that wont shutdown?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, apache-tomee

I'm trying to use a new installation of TomEE as a local server in Netbeans but there's another instance of Tomcat that will never shutdown no matter how many times I kill the process using task manager.

I know that Tomcat is installed properly because when I visit

> http://localhost:8080/

I see Tomcat's home page. But the problem goes way beyond that. When I change the port number in Netbeans, TomEE creates another instance on the exact same port number and the IDE throws me the error: Tomcat could not start: XXXX port number is already in used.

Example: I change the port 8080 to 8085. When I go in my browser, I can now see Tomcat's home page on `http://localhost:8085/` AND ALSO on `http://localhost:8080/`. TomEE will run as many instances as I change ports and never allow NO port to be used but in the browser I can see Tomcat's home page...

What is causing this? How can I stop this from happening? I have tried many things suggested by BalusC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre) and none of what he suggested helped me.

I restarted my computer many times but every time I run Netbeans, history repeats itself. I'm using the `.zip` version of [TomEE Plume](http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html). I unpacked the files in `C://`. There is no other instance of tomcat neither there is another server installed in that directory. I removed all others (GlassFish, Wamp and Tomcat 8.0.2). There is only TomEE now.

Comment: You can specify different JMX ports for running multiple tomcat's. IntelliJ IDEA allows that, I'm not sure about NetBeans. Regarding killing the process, you can know the process Id using `lsof i :8080` , find the PID, kill it using `kill -15 <pid>`

Comment: The problem is the same as @Mugi4ok's. So it is a possible duplicate. The full answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647156/tomee-starts-but-netbeans-gives-failed-to-start-error)