# Tomcat start not recognised by IDE

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, tomee-7

I am using Netbeans 11 to deploy a WAR file. When using RUN, the IDE starts Tomcat, which shows the startup message:

```
INFO - Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
INFO - Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
INFO - Server startup in 815 ms
```

However, the IDE "Run" tab shows that the start failed, after the timeout:

```
Deploying on TomEE
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Starting of Tomcat failed.
```

Somehow the IDE is not detecting Tomcat properly, since Tomcat is indeed running and listening on port 8080. I have tried [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647156/tomee-starts-but-netbeans-gives-failed-to-start-error), especially the one with the IDE proxy and the connector, but none works.

---

As per comments:

1) I am running TomEE, although I think there is no difference from Netbeans point of view (or even from TomEE itself) with regards to my issue. Honestly, I think it is a Netbeans - Tomcat communication issue, TomEE just adds some libraries and other stuff that would affect later.

2) I was using a custom `server.xml`, but now I am using the original one:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- TomEE plugin for Tomcat -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" xpoweredBy="false" server="Apache TomEE" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation with the JSSE engine. When
         using the JSSE engine, the JSSE configuration attributes must be used.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" xpoweredBy="false" server="Apache TomEE" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the APR/native implementation. When using the
         APR/native implementation or the OpenSSL engine with NIO or NIO2 then
         the OpenSSL configuration attributes must be used.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" xpoweredBy="false" server="Apache TomEE" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

3) Tomcat stars correctly and I see the port 8080 opened in my computer. Actually I have to manually kill the process to be able to attempt a new run from Netbeans again, otherwise it will complain that the port is already open. Meanwhile, Netbeans just wait and wait... and at some point after "waiting for Tomcat" it just say it fails, like if it could not recognise Tomcat is ON. Tomcat stays running like nobody has communicated with it. So no other strange logs anywhere.

4) From Netbans I can only "start", never stop because it has not detected Tomcat is running. So the "stop" command is disabled, as you said. Tomcat is running but the IDE never detected it running.

5) This happens all the time, I am not able to run any project from the IDE.

---

Netbeans log says:

```
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.deploy.TomcatManager]: TomEE version TOMEE_15, type TOMEE_PLUS
INFO [null]: Last record repeated again.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment]
org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerException: Starting of Tomcat failed.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerInstance._start(ServerInstance.java:1457)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerInstance.startTarget(ServerInstance.java:1400)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerInstance.startTarget(ServerInstance.java:1204)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerInstance.start(ServerInstance.java:1082)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.startTargets(TargetServer.java:547)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:190)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.execution.DeploymentHelper.perform(DeploymentHelper.java:185)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.execution.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:70)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:303)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:128)
```

Comment: [1] If you are deploying to TomEE rather than Tomcat (and based on the "Run" snippet it looks you are), could you update your question to make that clear? [2] Is it possible to post **server.xml**? [3] Any relevant messages in Tomcat's log at the time of the _"Tomcat failed"_ message? [4] Is there any problem apart from that incorrect message (_"Starting of Tomcat failed"_) being logged? For example, if you try to stop the server from NetBeans is the **Stop** menu entry for Tomcat disabled even though Tomcat is running? [5] Does this happen all the time, or intermittently?

Comment: OK. [1] Is there anything of relevance being written to the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**)? [2] It doesn't help you at all, but just FYI some else is reporting a similar issue with Wildlfly on NetBeans 11.2: [Netbeans does not know that Wildfly already started](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59303601/2985643). [3] Although I cannot reproduce either problem, perhaps this is a NetBeans 11.x issue? [4] Since this is a reproducible error, perhaps consider [raising a NetBeans bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-3582?filter=allopenissues).

Comment: Thanks. The log suggests that the `ExecutionChecker.executionResult` failed (see update in my question). So no much from what we knew. I will reinstall again Netbeans as I did with Tomcat, probably using a different version.

Comment: Right - that stack trace doesn't really add anything new. It seems there a few old NetBeans bug reports of Wildlfy and NetBeans not communicating properly, though I saw nothing for Wildlfy 15. I'm not sure reinstalling NetBeans will achieve anything, but upgrading to NetBeans 11.2 and/or Wildfly 18 might. Another fairly simple thing to try in your existing environment (if it's feasible) is to use a different server, [such as Payara](https://www.payara.fish/software/downloads/) which has worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: OK! After a lot of testing I think I am getting to somewhere. It seems the problem is related to the network interfaces - my computer has two, one for Internet, one for an internal network (needed to deploy the WAR after testing). If I disable the internal one, then Tomcat is apparently detected. Something is not managed correctly. (For the record, I also tried Netbeans 11.2 and 10.0 and didn't work)

Comment: I had the problem in NetBeans 11.1 and 11.3. I did not have the problem in NetBeans 12.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from a computer with two network interfaces. Somehow, Netbeans (most likely, unless Tomcat has something to do) is wrongly managing the situation, and it is unable to detect that Tomcat started.

I don't really know how to solve it, but I disconnected the second interface and it seems to work. It is very annoying and inconvenient, but it is a valid workaround.

I discovered this because `sudo` was really slow, and I found that there is an issue where sudo gets very slow on machines with two or more network interfaces... Unrelated, but ways to solve it: [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1272414) (`echo "Set probe_interfaces false" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudo.conf`)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it got solved by using an older version of tomcat.

I encountered the problem using Netbeans 11.1 and 11.3.

I received this error with tomcat 8.5.54 and 9.0.34.
Tomcat worked OK using version 8.5.49

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! In my case that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I googled and stackoverflowed, not solve until I saw the article here:
https://www.mail-archive.com/commits@netbeans.apache.org/msg24509.html

I downloaded source code of NetBeans11.1 and built it with command,

```
ant -Dcluster.config=full
```

It costs abut 17 minutes. after that, I run  with

```
ant tryme
```

Then I setup the tomcat settings in tools->servers and opened my project. Then I tried to run it. Amazing, it works fine now.

Apparently, it is a bug of NetBeans. And it is not hard to solve in the NetBeans side.

Comment: I found that only replace one jar file in NetBeans11.1 bin package would fix the issue. That is the org-netbeans-modules-tomcat5.jar under enterprise/modules.

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat server.xml, for , try adding:

**server="Apache-Coyote/1.1"**

As full example, this is what worked for us:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" server="Apache-Coyote/1.1" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```