# Netbeans & Tomcat starts fail

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, netbeans-8

my problem is simple ( but I can't figure how to solve it ) 
I installed the last version of netbeans ( 8.1 ) and I activated the java EE java Se module and installed glassfish & tomcat 8.0.27.0 on my system.

The problem : 
Glassfish is starting well but tomcat wont launch no matter the version or the location of the serveur, the only output that i have is this :

> Le fichier sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable.
>
> Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base"
>
> Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\ApacheTomcat8.0.27"
>
> Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\temp"
>
> Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73"
>
> Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\ApacheTomcat8.0.27\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\ApacheTomcat8.0.27\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"

Any idea how to solve it ?

PS: "Le fichier sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable." mean : "the specified file cannot be found"

Comment: I assume all the paths mentioned above are valid? If you run tomcat as a service, you might have to right click on the tomcat icon and open java tab and change java virtual machine path or just set "use default".

Comment: if by " valid" you mean that they exists yeah i checked that all of that path go on somewhere ;)
Anyway I'm using tomcat only in the netbeans interface and in the "platform" tab the java platform used is "JDK 1.8 (Default).

Comment: on what port is your Tomcat running? A common reason why Tomcat won't start is that a different process has already allocated the TCP/IP port (8080 by default) that Tomcat wants to use to accept connections. Open a browser and go to http://localhost:8080. What can you see?

Comment: nah i checked the ports and it was not in use,Anyway i found why : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225764/starting-of-tomcat-failed-from-netbeans?rq=1

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i saw an another post on stack. 
[Starting of Tomcat failed from Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225764/starting-of-tomcat-failed-from-netbeans?rq=1)

Tested that solution and it worked.

Weird ...