# Netbeans 8: how to deploy on save with tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, maven, wicket, tomcat8, netbeans-8

I'm trying to deploy-on-save a sample Wicket project from Netbeans 8.0.2 with pom.xml generated as shown here: http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html. I have added Tomcat to servers and added an admin user and password (checked tomcat-users.xml, of course). When I "Run" the project, Tomcat starts, but the project is not deployed. The "Run" output shows

```
NetBeans: Deploying on tomcat8
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
```

... and once I "Terminate" Tomcat from Servers tab, the build goes ahead and ends up with a WAR file generated in the project's target directory.

I haven't done any changes to the default Tomcat configuration other than adding a user.

By contrast, deploy-on-save works fine with Glassfish-4.1.

I've tried to change the server port and adding `<netbeans.hint.deploy.server>t8</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>` to pom.xml as some posts suggested (for earlier netbeans versions, though) - but no success so far.

So, is it possible to configure deploy-on-save for tomcat-8.5 in netbeans 8, and if yes, then how?

Comment: Might this problem be solved by the description found in: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225764/starting-of-tomcat-failed-from-netbeans> ?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhaa, upgrading to Netbeans 8.2 (from 8.02) did the trick!

Now, when you "Run" the app, another window pops up and asks for manager password again but just once. That is, the same you gave when adding a server. It seems that one has to add `<role rolename="manager-script"/>` to tomcat-users.xml manually to avoid this double-asking.

After the first run, the app is re-built and re-deployed on Save.