# Starting tomcat failed

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

Starting of Tomcat failed, check whether the C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\bin\catalina.bat and related scripts are executable.

Been having this problem in netbeans. How to solve the problem? Please help.

Comment: This might solve your problem [starting tomcat failed from netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225764/starting-of-tomcat-failed-from-netbeans?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the solutions posted here:
https://forums.netbeans.org/topic62626.html
It worked for me.