# Apache Tomcat/9.0.31 server does not start in Netbeans 8.2 on MAC

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans-8

I can start/shutdown the Tomcat server using my terminal but on NetBeans, it stays on `starting` for a few minutes then I get the `server failed to start` error.

Things I have tried:

- adjust the `server.xml` `<Connector />`
- uncheck the "Use IDE Proxy settings" box from **platform** tab in Server settings
- take off or add quotes to the "JAVA_OPTS" in `catalina.bat` file
- add different roles to the `tomcat-users.xml`
- try everything here [Starting of Tomcat failed from Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225764/starting-of-tomcat-failed-from-netbeans)

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

```
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 5 2020 19:32:12 UTC
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.31.0
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.15.3
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_191-b12
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/Aereli/Apache
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /Library/Tomcat
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/Aereli/Apache/conf/logging.properties
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/Aereli/Apache
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Library/Tomcat
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/Aereli/Apache/temp
15-Feb-2020 21:12:39.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/Aereli/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
15-Feb-2020 21:12:40.310 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
15-Feb-2020 21:12:40.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [789] milliseconds
15-Feb-2020 21:12:40.483 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
15-Feb-2020 21:12:40.483 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
15-Feb-2020 21:12:40.509 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/Users/Aereli/Apache/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml]
15-Feb-2020 21:12:40.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/Users/Aereli/Apache/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml] has finished in [356] ms
15-Feb-2020 21:12:40.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/Users/Aereli/Apache/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml]
15-Feb-2020 21:12:40.867 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [] in deployment descriptor [/Users/Aereli/Apache/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] has been ignored
15-Feb-2020 21:12:40.903 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/Users/Aereli/Apache/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] has finished in [37] ms
15-Feb-2020 21:12:40.921 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
15-Feb-2020 21:12:40.958 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [561] milliseconds
```

Comment: As a general rule, during unit testing, it is better to export the war and test it on a tomcat started from the terminal. While in theory starting and testing from IDE is a faster option, in practice it is fraught with many problems. I don't use NetBeans, however, in Eclipe, many a times the previously deployed war does not clear properly and expected result is not received, leading to misleading searches through code-base. This problem gets more severe as dependencies of the war becomes more complex, sometime traces are also not written properly. This is more of a pointer from experience.

Comment: Your log output doesn't show the error from your question. It shows the server starting. What's your problem?

Comment: @Ironluca Thanks for the tip, I decided to run with Eclipse and trash the project from Netbeans. The server turns on just find from the Terminal but as you had mentioned, can be buggy from the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem with Netbeans 12. I searched a lot in the internet and all the solutions didn't work for me. Finally I **updated my JDK** to the latest version and tomcat started working like a charm. Try updating your JDK to the latest version. That might help you. I believe Netbeans versions tend to depend on the JDK you use.